# How to connect to external display via hdmi?

Tags: release-hera, hdmi

I have installed elementary hera 5.1 on my Asus Vivobook and i want to connect to use my Hisense TV as an external monitor via HDMI. However I have been unable to successfully do this. Sometimes it won't displlay anything, sometimes it shows just the homescreen on one screen and opens apps on the other screen, and if i try to mirror, i get a massive zoomed in picture on both the laptop and tv and have to unplug the cable. I have tried researching this but have not found any method to do this.
If anyone knows how to connect to my TV, please reply.

Thanks